# jQuery forcing radio buttons to check wrong button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, radio-button

Im using jQuery to put the value from a radio button and input it into a field.
But the jQuery is forcing the last button to always be selected.
The radio input in Question is the 5th one down called Please Specify

Check http://designfitz.com/product/thesis

This is the code

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('input[name="input_88"]').click(function () {
    var themethod =jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#input_3_7").val(themethod);
  }).click();
});
```

I've deleted all other javascript on the page and disabled all plugins in wordpress and it still happens.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`input_88` will be selected on page load as you are triggering click event on it*

remove that `.click()` in the end -

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('input[name="input_88"]').click(function () {
    var themethod =jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#input_3_7").val(themethod);
  });
});
```